# Output not printing without fflush(stdout)

Tags: c, io, stdout, fflush

I don't understand why sometimes I need to use `fflush()` and sometimes not.

My program is segfaulting at the moment and I am debugging it with print statements. When a program segfaults, does `stdout` not flush its buffer automatically?

Comment: `stdout` is just a pointer, it doesn't "do" anything by itself. The real question would be, "doesn't the OS flush all open files?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I don't understand why sometimes I need to use fflush() and sometimes
>   not.

Sometimes the `stdio` buffers are flushed sometimes they aren't. For example simply including a "\n" in the printed stuff will typically flush it (because `stdout` is by default line-buffered when attached to a terminal).

> When a program segfaults, does stdout not flush its buffer
>   automatically ?

Stdio buffers are flushed by `exit`. When a signal (such as `SIGSEGV`) kills a process, **`exit` is not called**. Another way to exit a process without flushing the `stdio` buffers is to use the Unix-specific call `_exit`.

Answer (score 1):

No, why should it. The program gets killed by the operating system. If a segfault occurs, the program is no longer in a meaningful state, so nothing *can* safely happen at that point other than immediate termination.

(And don't nobody try to register a signal handler for `SIGSEGV`.)

Comment: In some cases, registering a signal handler for `SIGSEGV` is valid - for instance if you're making a read-only mapping with `mmap`, you can catch and `longjmp` out of write attempts on it with a signal handler, and this is 100% (as far as POSIX is concerned) portable and valid as long as the write was not being performed by an async-signal-unsafe function.

Comment: @R..: as usual with "pseudo-advice": once you understand when it's safe to ignore, you can safely ignore it ;-) In any event, you must terminate the program eventually; you cannot recover from the signal.

Answer (score 0):

> "I cannot figure out why fflush (stdout) is called here in this code
>   I try to comment this line and behavior was exactly the same."
>
> Because you're not guaranteed to see previous printf() output if that
>   output doesn't end in a newline.
>
> Basically, you only need it if you're displaying say a prompt without
>   a newline, and you want to make sure the user can see it.

See [this site.](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/61997-when-where-use-fflush-stdout.html)