# if statement inside while that depends on the same variable that while depends on

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

consider the below programs.
I would like to know why this codes behave in different way.Thankyou in advance.

this doesnot print any

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;

    while(i < 10) {
        if(i < 7)
            printf("value is%d", i++); 
    }
}
```

while this does

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i = 0;

    while(i < 10) {
        if(i < 7)
            printf("value is%d\n", i++);
    }
}
```

Comment: its called flushing

Comment: By default stdout is line buffered. This means that (unless you fill some internal buffer), it will not actually print anything until you print a newline, flush stdout or the program exits (which forces a flush of stdout). Your first program never prints a newline, flushes stdout or exits.

Comment: Flushing would also happen when your program terminates. But as your program never stops, this won't happen.

Answer (score 5):

First note both your programs never exit. When `i` hits `7` it's game over and your stuck forever doing nothing.

Second note the only difference is printing a new line. That should have been your clue. Since the loop is infinite you never print a new line or exit - both things flush STDOUT. Until you flush STDOUT you're just accumulating what you're trying to print in a buffer. Only the flushing will get it on screen, and clean the buffer.

@chux added a good point:

Buffering of STDOUT (or IN or ERR) is implementation defined, meaning different flavors of Linux, Windows, and so forth may display different behavior. Obviously in the OP STDOUT is buffered - as no output appears.

Comment: I think, the C language does not demand `exit` to flush... Am I wrong ?

Comment: I checked now, yes, explicit `exit` is required to flush``Next,  all  open  streams  with  unwritten  buffered  data  are  ﬂushed,  all  open  streams  are
closed, and all ﬁles created by the tmpfile function are removed.``

Comment: "Until you flush STDOUT you're just accumulating what you're trying to print in a buffer." --> Maybe. It is implementation defined behavior.   `stdout` might print out under various conditions and modes and not necessarily just accumulate. See [What are the rules of automatic flushing stdout buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39536212/2410359)

Comment: @chux correct, but it will only "print" when it's "flushed". I just gave the common occurrences. Obviously STDOUT is not flushed in OPs example.

Comment: Disagree with only "print" when it's "flushed".  It is implementation defined behavior when the printing occurs without a "flush". With a `"flush" the behavior is well defined.

Comment: @chux Agree then, I misunderstood you. I'm adding your point to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `printf()` it just puts your data into `STDOUT` buffer, its purpose is not to display onto screen. but when you use `\n` inside the `printf()` if flushes the `STDOUT` buffer on screen. you can also use `fflush()` if you are not using `\n`. 
From `fflush()` [man](http://man.he.net/?topic=fflush&section=all) page

> For  output streams, fflush() forces a write of all user-space buffered
>          data for the given output or update stream via the stream's  underlying
>          write function.  For input streams, fflush() discards any buffered data
>          that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not  been  con-
>          sumed by the application.  The open status of the stream is unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8316330/7917141).

> For example simply including a "\n" in the printed stuff will typically flush it (because stdout is by default line-buffered when attached to a terminal).

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i=0;
    while(i<10) {
        if(i<7)
            printf("value is%d",i++);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```